# C# How to pass properties to base class with optional values?

Tags: c#, .net

In the code example below, if HighValue and LowValue properties are not set by the client, how can I pass default values for these properties to the base class?

If there is a design mistake in this example setup, I'd like to thank you in advance for warning me.

```csharp
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int scaleHigh, int scaleLow)
    {
        ScaleHigh = scaleHigh;
        ScaleLow = scaleLow;
    }

    public int ScaleHigh { get; }
    public int ScaleLow { get; }
}


public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar(Bar bar)
        : base(bar.ScaleHigh, bar.ScaleLow)
    {
        HighValue = SomeHelper.ReCalculate(bar.HighValue);
        LowValue = SomeHelper.ReCalculate(bar.LowValue);
    }

    public int HighValue { get; }
    public int LowValue { get; }
}


public class SomeHelper
{
    public static int ReCalculate(int scale)
    {
        return scale * 5;
    }
}


public class Client : Bar
{
    public Client(Bar bar) : base(bar) { }

    public int Request(bool condition)
    {
        return condition ? HighValue : LowValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do `Foo` and `Bar` **actually** represent in your program code? We can't just give general advice for OOP design problems without knowing what the objects actually are. And of course, in general, you _probably_ don't need inheritance to solve modelling problems.

Comment: Foo is the class with general properties, Bar is the class with specific properties.

Comment: You shouldn't be (ab)using inheritance as a substitute for mixins or for shared-members. While C# (still) doesn't support mixins or data-extensions, you can still compose `record` types to achieve a similar effect with defined interfaces so you can have the IDE handle the tedious forwarding logic for you.

Comment: The inheritance relationship between `Client` and `Bar` seems contrived, and could be changed to composition relationship, such that the necessary values are retrieved off the `Bar` member reference in `Request` instead of accessed from `base`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a bug in your bar class, since it doesn't have a default constructor, you will never be able to create the object, since it will be a recursion forever - each new instance would neeed another and so on

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar(Bar bar)
        : base(bar.ScaleHigh, bar.ScaleLow)
    {
        HighValue = SomeHelper.ReCalculate(bar.HighValue);
        LowValue = SomeHelper.ReCalculate(bar.LowValue);
    }

    public int HighValue { get; }
    public int LowValue { get; }
}
```

you can fix it by adding another constructor like this

```
public Bar(int scaleHigh=0, int scaleLow=0, int highValue=0, int lowValue=0)
        : base(scaleHigh, scaleLow)
    {
        HighValue = SomeHelper.ReCalculate(highValue);
        LowValue = SomeHelper.ReCalculate(lowValue);
    }
```

Comment: `Bar(int scaleHigh=0, int scaleLow=0, int highValue=0, int lowValue=0)` - this is only valid *if* zero is a meaningful value for those properties, otherwise the object will be in an invalid state.

Comment: @Dai I posted existing class, and now I added my suggestions

Comment: @Dai Of course the OP can change those to whatever he wants

Comment: @Alaska yes, a good notice.

Comment: +1 thanks @Serge. yes, this is a valid way to pass optional parameters. but I have too much classes in my project like this. and too much parameters, so I have to use a model class.

Comment: @Emre.Microsoft Why not use a composition of `record` types?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public int LowValue { get; } = 0; //You can change these values.
public int HighValue { get; } = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply @Darren Peterson. I saw this solution in another question too. But I was not sure that I could use this solution because ReSharper gave a "Property Initializer value ignored during initialization" warning.

Comment: @Emre.Microsoft That warning is because your (only) constructor always sets new values for those properties, so the initializer is moot.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I misunderstand, but I believe you want to set default values of Bar if they are not set? In what case would the constructor not set the values?

In the case that you didn't set those in your constructor, one thing you can consider is making the types `int?` and then set the variable like this:

`public int? HighValue => HighValue ?? (defaultValue)`